Is there a third party to replace the Android Play Install Referrer Library?
If you are an account that has logged into the Google Play store as a business account, the installReferrer recognizes that the utm information has not been set, such as "utm_source=(not%20set) & utm_medium=(not%20set).
I found out the reason is that the Play store constantly checks all the accounts logged in to that phone and if there are accounts managed by the company, it checks to reset the referrer token.
If I log in with a business account, I wonder why I reset the token and if there is another library that can get utm information from the referrer url even if I log in with a business account.
Also, I was wondering if there are any other cases where not set could occur except when I logged in with a business account.
When I logged in to the Play Store as a regular account instead of a business account in the same environment, the utm information was not lost and taken correctly. I want to track the utm information on my business account as well.
